# Keyword arguments with non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that queries via an API. It looks like this:

```
def lookup(table, *fields, **query):
    # table - the table to query through the API
    # fields - the fields I want returned in the response
    # query - the query I encode and send

    # do some stuff
```

That's been working fine so far, but I came across a case where I want to include in the query an item where the key is of the form `some_field.some_sub_field`. Python doesn't like parsing that, and I'm wondering if there is a good way to do that without rewriting `lookup` to expect a `dict` instead of keyword arguments.

The best I can come up with looks like this:

```
response = lookup('table', 'name', name='item', **{'status.name': 'production'})
```

I think that looks ugly. Is there a better way of doing that? Right now I'm looking at creating a `dict` for the query above the call and destructuring the entire query.

```
query = {'name': 'item', 'status.name': 'production'}
response = lookup('table', 'name', **query)
```

Comment: Django uses double underscores.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not my own API, if that's what you're thinking